# Powershell script to find physical memory usages with process name

Tags: powershell, memory

I have created a script for CPU usages with instance name like as below. Could anyone please help me to create a script for physical memory usages and to get page file status?

```
Get-Counter'\Process(*)\% Processor Time' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples | Select-Object -Property instancename, cookedvalue | Sort-Object -Property cookedvalue -Descending | Select-Object -First 5 | ft InstanceName,@{L='CPU';E={($_.Cookedvalue/100).toString('P')}}

InstanceName     CPU     
------------     ---     
_total           100.95 %
idle             91.74 % 
powershell_ise   4.61 %  
taskmgr          0.77 %  
coreserviceshell 0.77 %
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant find one for the Page file, but This is for the Memory, Based on your code, just replaced the counter:

```
Get-Counter '\Process(*)\Working Set' | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples | 
Select-Object -Property instancename, cookedvalue | 
Sort-Object -Property cookedvalue -Descending | Select-Object -First 5 |
FT InstanceName,@{L='Memory';E={($_.Cookedvalue / 1000).toString()}}
```

Sorted by Percentage:

```
$Total = Get-Counter '\Process(*)\Working Set' | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples | ? {$_.instancename -eq "_total"} | Select -ExpandProperty CookedValue

Get-Counter '\Process(*)\Working Set' | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples | 
Select-Object -Property instancename, cookedvalue | 
Sort-Object -Property cookedvalue -Descending | Select-Object -First 5 |
 ft InstanceName,@{L='Memory';E={([System.Math]::Round($_.Cookedvalue / $total * 100).toString()) + " %"}}
```